# Endeca "how to check if a lock is held" LockManger isLockHeld in Shell script

Tags: endeca

How do we check in a shell script if there is an update_lock when running the pipeline baseline_update.sh script?  The return status is always 0.

```
./control/baseline_update.sh
echo "isLockHeld " $?
```

When we run Endeca's command to check isLockHeld the same 4 INFO lines return for both scenarios when there is a lock and when there is not a lock.
./control/runcommand.sh LockManager isLockHeld update_lock

> [12.12.13 10:55:44] INFO: Checking definition from AppConfig.xml against existing EAC provisioning.
> [12.12.13 10:55:45] INFO: Updating provisioning for component 'Forge'
>
> [12.12.13 10:55:45] INFO: Updating definition for component 'Forge'
>
> [12.12.13 10:55:46] INFO: Definition updated.

We were expecting isLockHeld to return a boolean 'True' or 'False'.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35639_01/DeploymentTemplate.321/apidoc/eacToolkit/com/endeca/soleng/eac/toolkit/base/LockManager.html#isLockHeld(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

eaccmd.sh list-flags --app your_app_name

You can then remove them with

eaccmd.sh remove-all-flags --app your_app_name